# Find a primitive for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3, \sqrt[3]2$) over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory

I want to find a primitive for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3, \sqrt[3]2$) over $\mathbb{Q}$.
I think this would be $\alpha= \sqrt3 + \sqrt[3]2$ but how would I justify this? Is it something to do with the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$? 
Or can I just show that you can form all elements of the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3, \sqrt[3]2$) over $\mathbb{Q}$ using a linear combination of $\sqrt3 + \sqrt[3]2$? The basis being {$1,\sqrt3, \sqrt[3]2, \sqrt3\sqrt[3]2,  2^{2/3}\sqrt3, 2^{2/3}$}.

Answer (score 3):

$(\alpha-\sqrt{3})^3 = 2       $

$\alpha^3 -3\alpha^2\sqrt3+9\alpha-3\sqrt3     =2                    $

$\sqrt3 = \frac{2- \alpha^3-9\alpha}{-3\alpha^2-3}                $

thus $\sqrt3 \in Q[\alpha] $

obviously then $\sqrt[3]2$ is in $Q[\alpha]$ too

Thus you get your whole basis.